# Label columns based on grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column that consists of unique values for each id (each id has numerous rows associated with it), if the id has the tag answered associated with any of its rows, all the rows associated with that id should be labelled answered. If all the rows associated with an id have an unanswered tag, all the rows should be labelled as unanswered (this is currently what happens)

This is code I have written:

import numpy as np

```
conds = [file.data__answered_at.isna(),file.data__answered_at.notna()]
choices = ["not answered","answered"]
file['call_status'] = np.select(conds,choices,default=np.nan)

 data__id   call_status       rank
  1            answered        1
  1          not_answered      2
  1            answered        3
  2          not_answered      1
  2             answered       2
  3          not_answered      1
  4            answered        1
  4          not_answered      2
  5          not_answered      1
  5          not_answered      2
```

In this case the desired outcome would be

```
   data__id   call_status       rank
  1            answered        1
  1            answered        2
  1            answered        3
  2            answered        1
  2            answered        2
  3          not_answered      1
  4            answered        1
  4            answered        2
  5          not_answered      1
  5          not_answered      2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test at least one `answered` per groups and set values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['call_status'].eq('answered').groupby(df['data__id']).transform('any')
```

Or get all `data__id` filtered by another column and test membership by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask = df['data__id'].isin(df.loc[df['call_status'].eq('answered'), 'data__id'].unique())
```

---

```
df.loc[mask, 'call_status'] = 'answered'
print (df)
   data__id   call_status  rank
0         1      answered     1
1         1      answered     2
2         1      answered     3
3         2      answered     1
4         2      answered     2
5         3  not_answered     1
6         4      answered     1
7         4      answered     2
8         5  not_answered     1
9         5  not_answered     2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) here and check if [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) of the rows are equal to `answered`.

Then we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally fill in `answered` or `not_answered`

```
m = file.groupby('data__id')['call_status'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('answered').any())

file['call_status'] = np.where(m, 'answered', 'not_answered')
```

**Output**

```
  data__id   call_status  rank
0         1      answered     1
1         1      answered     2
2         1      answered     3
3         2      answered     1
4         2      answered     2
5         3  not_answered     1
6         4      answered     1
7         4      answered     2
8         5  not_answered     1
9         5  not_answered     2
```